# How to select reference value of Property in Blazor server side DataGrid

Tags: blazor-server-side

I'm struggling with the syntax here, can't find the correct form.
I want to display the "Name" of SiteModel based on "IdSite" of "GatewayModel"

```
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="GatewayModel" 
       Property="IdSite" Title="Site Name" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" >
    <Template Context="sites">
        // can't figure out what to do here
    </Template>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>

@code {
    List<GatewayModel> gateways;
    GatewayModel gmdl = new GatewayModel();

    List<SiteModel> sites;
    SiteModel smdl = new SiteModel();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string gatesql = "SELECT * FROM gatewaymodel;";
        gateways = await _data.LoadData<GatewayModel, dynamic>(gatesql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("MainDB"));

        string sitesql = "SELECT * FROM sitemodel;";
        sites = await _data.LoadData<SiteModel, dynamic>(sitesql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("MainDB"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would highly recommend you to post this on [Radzen's forum](https://forum.radzen.com/c/blazor-components/10) - they would be able to help faster and with better answers, since they created it.

With the limited amount of code given I can only give some hints on how to achieve the behavior you want.

1. The RadzenDataGridColumn must be inside a RadzenDataGrid. **Assuming it's not there.*
2. Inside the  you use regual html and Blazor markup
3. Please read through their [documentation (data grid docs)](https://www.radzen.com/documentation/blazor/datagrid/) and [examples (example on using the Template)](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-column-template) they have.